# Android: get nearest street from marker point

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

Am adding markers in my android app, but I need to make one feature, if I add marker not on street, I need marker to be added on the nearest known street. Like in this example: [Add marker to nearest known street](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_snap.htm), but  I need to make it with android.

this is my marker coordinates:

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        markerLatLng = new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title("my marker");
```

Now I need execute async task to send coordinates to google and retrieve nearest road coordinates.What url should I use for that?

Then am planning to add coordinates to arrayList:

```
locationArray.add(new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
```

And show marker on my map:

```
mGoogleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

I enabled in my API manager : `Google Maps Directions API` and `Google Maps Roads API`

The question is ,what `URL` in my `AsynTask` should I use to get nearest street coordinates?

Maybe I need to use this: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?parameters` and add my marker coordinates to parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You know how to use json i recommend the following:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=yourLat,yourLng
```

In the response you will have all information about that LatLng, nearest street and number, city, states, country and plenty more.

Comment: so, to get nearest street, should I use `DirectionsAPI` or `GeocodeAPI`?

Comment: Geocode, if try this in directions api you will get "invalid request".

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to snap the coordinate to the nearest road you should consider the Roads API that has a Nearest roads functionality.

Have a look at the documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/nearest

So the URL that you can use in the async task is something like `https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads?parameters&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

If your purpose is to find the nearest available street address the Reverse Geocoding is good for this as was suggested by Henrique.

Comment: The location is not very accurate by using nearestRoads, sometimes the marker misses the road. To be more accureate please use: https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=54.473155, -6.342999&interpolate=true&key=API_KEY